# Data-starved channels are delaying watermarks

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a event-time processing pipeline
Something like:

```
env.keyBy(_.key).process(myProcessFunction)
```

The process function only processes watermarked events (this is because it requires the events to be ordered, and depending on that ordering emits an event). Such a process function has been shown many times, the first similar one to what I use i found on google [here](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/process/CarEventSort.java).  In short it looks like this:

```
class MyProcessFunction extends ProcessFunction[Input, Output] {
   def open(config: Configuration) {
      //setup an ordered queue here
   }

   def processElement(event: Input, ..., out: Collector[Output]) {
      updateQueue(_.enqueue(event))
      context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(even.timestamp)
   }

   def onTimer(timestamp: Long, ..., out: Collector[Output]) {
      val watermark = ctx.timerService().currentWatermark()
      updateQueue{ queue =>
         while(queue.headOption.exists(_.timestamp < watermark) { 
            val event = queue.dequeue()
            out.collect(event)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, lets say I use a parallelism of 8, since in most cases many keys flow through this system. I wrote myself some integration/unit tests that work with a small set of data. Lets say in this data we have only 4 keys. What I ran into is a possibly not so well documented behaviour of flink.

If you look into StreamInputProcessor.processInput, specifically on [line 189](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/io/StreamInputProcessor.java#L184) that handles watermarks and follow into [StatusWatermarkValve.inputWatermark](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c3472b95e54106658d247e7f4bf3b4ea6e2435f6/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/streamstatus/StatusWatermarkValve.java#L111) and finally [StatusWatermarkValve.findAndOutputNewMinWatermarkAcrossAlignedChannels](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c3472b95e54106658d247e7f4bf3b4ea6e2435f6/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/streamstatus/StatusWatermarkValve.java#L173) you will find, that the watermark that gets assigned to a stream is the MIN of all 'active' Channels for that stream. During runtime debugging, I found that since these channels are initialized as ACTIVE (constructor of StatusWatermarkValve), they will set the streams watermark to Long.MIN_VALUE, until at least a single watermark gets its way into each channel.

This results in a behaviour where if you have my above outlined processing program and you only have 4 keys, they will never be processed.

I am a bit suprised that watermarks do not get propagated into every channel (probably memory optimizations). Secondly I am VERY suprised that channels are set as ACTIVE by default, even before any event gets passed into them.

**My question is: Is it somehow possible to work around this? I want to be able to process those 4 keys.**

I talked about an integration test, so the solution could simply be to reduce parallelism in the test, or add keys. However I can think of times where I dislike this behaviour during live execution: During day I have much more events than during night, so I size my parallelism in a way to handle the day, but during night the pipeline will be starved for data => some of the channels will be unused and therefore will stall the other channels watermarks. This almost leads me to believe this is a bug, but I cant be sure, there might be a reason for this being intended.

Comment: i found a possibly related bug report - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5479 it is related because what I left out of my description is that I am using a kafka source